# Mysql order by exception

Tags: mysql

I need the var_name column with 'other' to be at the end, so I tried this. It works but I need to order the first select statement by perc, the UNION won't let me. I'm sure using a UNION is probably wrong anyway.

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt,(count(*)/$cty)*100 AS perc, var_name
FROM tbl_answers
WHERE int_question = $id_question AND var_response <> ''
AND var_name <> 'comments' AND var_name <> 'Other'
GROUP BY var_name
UNION
SELECT count(*) AS cnt,(count(*)/$cty)*100 as perc,var_name
FROM tbl_answers
WHERE int_question = $id_question
AND var_response <> '' AND var_name <> 'comments' AND var_name = 'Other'
GROUP BY var_name
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this syntax

```
SELECT ....... ORDER BY ( var_name = 'Other' ), perc
```

because condition in MySQL returns 0 as false and 1 as true it will sort it ascending from var_name <> 'Other' to var_name = 'Other'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt, (count(*)/$cty)*100 AS perc, var_name 
FROM tbl_answers 
WHERE int_question = $id_question 
 AND var_response <> '' 
 AND var_name <> 'comments' 
GROUP BY var_name 
ORDER BY (var_name = 'Other')  
       , perc
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a union to do this, just use a regular mysql ORDER BY:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt, (count(*)/$cty)*100 AS perc, var_name 
FROM tbl_answers 
WHERE int_question = $id_question and var_response <> '' AND var_name <> 'comments'
GROUP BY var_name
ORDER BY var_name = 'Other'
```